# Find the maximum determinant for each size Toeplitz matrix

Tags: math, fastest-code

For a fixed n, consider the n by n [Toeplitz matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) with entries which are either 0 or 1.  The aim is to find maximum determinant over all such Toeplitz matrices.

**Task**

For each `n` from 1 upwards, output the maximum determinant over all n by n Toeplitz matrices with entries which are either 0 or 1. There should be one output per `n` which should have the maximum determinant and also an example matrix that reaches it.

**Score**

Your score is the largest `n` your code gets to in 2 minutes on my computer.  To clarify a little, your code can run for 2 minutes in total, this is not 2 minutes per `n`.

**Tie breaker**

If two entries get the same `n` score then the winning entry will be the one that gets to the highest `n` in the shortest time on my machine. If the two best entries are equal on this criterion too then the winner will be the answer submitted first.

**Languages and libraries**

You can use any freely available language and libraries you like. I must be able to run your code so please include a full explanation for how to run/compile your code in linux if at all possible.

**My Machine** The timings will be run on my machine. This is a standard ubuntu install on an AMD FX-8350 Eight-Core Processor.  This also means I need to be able to run your code.

**Small answers**

For n = 1..10 the outputs should be 1,1,2,3,5,9,32,56,125,315

This sequence is not in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) and so the winning entry also gets to propose a new entry there.

**Entries so far**

- <strike>`n=10`</strike> `n=11` by Vioz in **Python**
- `n=9` by Tyilo in **C**
- `n=12` by Legendre in **J**
- `n=10` by Tensibai in **R**
- `n=14` by SteelRaven in **C++**
- `n=14` by RetoKoradi in **C++**

Comment: @AlexA. You are right and I have apologised. Luckily the two problems are very similar so he should easily be able to modify his code.

Comment: The solution by @Vioz comes up with a sequence that starts with 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 32. So the value for n=5 is different from what you list. Since all other values match, it looks like the solution is probably correct, and this is just a typo in the question?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Here are 10 possible binary Toeplitz matrices with maximum determinants for `n = 1..10`: https://ghostbin.com/paste/axkpa

Comment: Does our code need to prove that we have the matrix with the greatest determinant (e.g. by checking all of them), or can we just have an algorithm that generates a matrix with greatest determinant without proving it's optimal?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Well a proof is fine even it is cleverer than checking all possibilities. But I am not sure exactly what you meant.

Comment: Say I have a hill-climbing algorithm that tries to optimize for greatest determinant, which correctly finds a matrix with greatest determinant for n=1..15 but gives a matrix with suboptimal determinant for n>15. Would that be a valid submission for n=15?

Comment: @ThomasKwa That's a tricky one as someone else would have to write code to verify your answers!  I would love to see such a hill climbing answer but I don't think I can award a win to it sadly.

Comment: @Tyilo How high does it get?

Comment: Here's a better version of the Mathematica one: `Print["1: 1"];Do[m=Max@Table[d=IntegerDigits[c,2,2*n-1];Det[ToeplitzMatrix@@(Prepend@First@d/@Partition[Drop[d,1],n-1])],{c,0,2^(2*n-1)-1}];Print[n,": ",m],{n,2,100}]` It only gets to 9 in 2 minutes, so it's actually worse than my C version. (To actually run it you have to remove the `&zwnj;&#0803;` by stackexchange.)

Comment: @Lembik I can get to 11 in 2 mins with: `Print["1: 1"];Quiet@Do[m=Max@Table[d=IntegerDigits[c,2,2*n-1];Tr[First@LUDecomposition[ToeplitzMatrix@@(Prepend@First@d/@Partition[Drop[d,1],n-1])],Times],{c,0,2^(2*n-1)-1}];Print[n,": ",m],{n,2,10}]`

Comment: As an observation that may help others but I can't verify beyond 14.  It appears respective means of the top row and the first column of the Toeplitz matrix are always 0.4 <= m <= 0.6 for the maximum determinant.

Comment: I notice that all the matrices with the highest determinants have a 1 in the main diagonal. I figure it would be considered cheating to hardwire that?

Comment: @RetoKoradi The max is sometimes reached with 0s in the main diagonal, e.g. for `n=3` there is `[0,1,1;1,0,1;1,1,0]`, and the next one occurs for `n=6`. I checked that for `n=1..12` there is always at least one matrix with 1s in the main diagonal that reaches the max, but that's not the same as what you wrote.

Comment: @MitchSchwartz The best solution my code got for n=17 has 0 in the main diagonal. I did not check if there are tied solutions that have a 1 diagonal. So yes, assuming that the main diagonal is 1 would not work for very long.

Comment: One thing I find fascinating when looking at the numbers is that some results are powers of 2. So far, I got powers of 2 for n=1, 2, 3, 7, 15. Except for n=2, these are all values of n that are of the form 2^k-1. I know it's risky to draw conclusions from a few values. But the value for n=15 being **exactly** 2^17 is almost too good to be a coincidence. I wonder if there's some kind of pattern.

Comment: @RetoKoradi "So yes, assuming that the main diagonal is 1 would not work for very long." does not follow logically from "The best solution my code got for n=17 has 0 in the main diagonal. I did not check if there are tied solutions that have a 1 diagonal."

Comment: @MitchSchwartz Not strictly, yes. But at least it shoots down the initial idea that only matrices with diagonal 1 are worth trying. I guess your counter-example for n=3 was sufficient. I should probably extend my code to keep track of ties if we want to know for sure. :) Well, at least for the sizes it can complete, which should be up to n=20 in a weekend run.

Comment: @RetoKoradi It is always worth comparing to https://oeis.org/A003432 . For n = 15 the max for general (0,1) matrices is also 2^17   and this is a much more widely studied question..

Comment: @MitchSchwartz My code output 927472 (which is smaller than the maximum) for n=17 with the main diagonal = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## C++ with pthreads

This gets to n=14 in just under 1 minute on my machine. But since that's just a 2-core laptop, I hope that the 8-core test machine can finish n=15 in under 2 minutes. It takes about 4:20 minutes on my machine.

I was really hoping to come up with something more efficient. There has **got** to be a way to calculate the determinate of a binary matrix more efficiently. I wanted to come up with some kind of dynamic programming approach that counts the +1 and -1 terms in the determinant calculation. But it just hasn't quite come together so far.

Since the bounty is about to expire, I implemented the standard brute force approach:

- Loop over all possible Toeplitz matrices.
- Skip one of the two in each transposed matrix pair. Since the matrix is described by bitmask values, this is simple to do by skipping all values where the reverse of the bitmask is smaller than the bitmask itself.
- The determinate is calculated with a text book LR decomposition. Except for some minor performance tuning, the main improvement I made to the algorithm from my college numerical methods book is that I use a simpler pivot strategy.
- Parallelization is done with pthreads. Just using regular spacing for the values processed by each thread caused very bad load balancing, so I introduced some swizzling.

I tested this on Mac OS, but I used similar code on Ubuntu before, so I hope this will compile and run without a hitch:

1. Save the code in a file with a `.cpp` extension, e.g. `optim.cpp`.
2. Compile with `gcc -Ofast optim.cpp -lpthread -lstdc++`.
3. Run with `time ./a.out 14 8`. The first argument is the maximum `n`. 14 should finish in under 2 minutes for sure, but it would be great if you could try 15 as well. The second argument is the number of threads. Using the same value as the number of cores of the machine is normally a good start, but trying some variations could potentially improve the times.

Let me know if you have any problems building or running the code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

static int NMax = 14;
static int ThreadCount = 4;

static pthread_mutex_t ThreadMutex;
static pthread_cond_t ThreadCond;
static int BarrierCount = 0;

static float* MaxDetA;
static uint32_t* MaxDescrA;

static inline float absVal(float val)
{
    return val < 0.0f ? -val : val;
}

static uint32_t reverse(int n, uint32_t descr)
{
    uint32_t descrRev = 0;
    for (int iBit = 0; iBit < 2 * n - 1; ++iBit)
    {
        descrRev <<= 1;
        descrRev |= descr & 1;
        descr >>= 1;
    }

    return descrRev;
}

static void buildMat(int n, float mat[], uint32_t descr)
{
    int iDiag;
    for (iDiag = 1 - n; iDiag < 0; ++iDiag)
    {
        float val = static_cast<float>(descr & 1);
        descr >>= 1;
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < n + iDiag; ++iRow)
        {
            mat[iRow * (n + 1) - iDiag] = val;
        }
    }

    for ( ; iDiag < n; ++iDiag)
    {
        float val = static_cast<float>(descr & 1);
        descr >>= 1;
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < n - iDiag; ++iCol)
        {
            mat[iCol * (n + 1) + iDiag * n] = val;
        }
    }
}

static float determinant(int n, float mat[])
{
    float det = 1.0f;
    for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; ++k)
    {
        float maxVal = 0.0f;
        int pk = 0;
        for (int i = k; i < n; ++i)
        {
            float q = absVal(mat[i * n + k]);
            if (q > maxVal)
            {
                maxVal = q;
                pk = i;
            }
        }

        if (pk != k)
        {
            det = -det;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                float t = mat[k * n + j];
                mat[k * n + j] = mat[pk * n + j];
                mat[pk * n + j] = t;
            }
        }

        float s = mat[k * n + k];
        det *= s;

        s = 1.0f / s;
        for (int i = k + 1; i < n; ++i)
        {
            mat[i * n + k] *= s;
            for (int j = k + 1; j < n; ++j)
            {
                mat[i * n + j] -= mat[i * n + k] * mat[k * n + j];
            }
        }
    }

    det *= mat[n * n - 1];

    return det;
}

static void threadBarrier()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ThreadMutex);

    ++BarrierCount;
    if (BarrierCount <= ThreadCount)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&ThreadCond, &ThreadMutex);
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&ThreadCond);
        BarrierCount = 0;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ThreadMutex);
}

static void* threadFunc(void* pData)
{
    int* pThreadIdx = static_cast<int*>(pData);
    int threadIdx = *pThreadIdx;

    float* mat = new float[NMax * NMax];

    for (int n = 1; n <= NMax; ++n)
    {
        uint32_t descrRange(1u << (2 * n - 1));
        float maxDet = 0.0f;
        uint32_t maxDescr = 0;

        uint32_t descrInc = threadIdx;
        for (uint32_t descrBase = 0;
             descrBase + descrInc < descrRange;
             descrBase += ThreadCount)
        {
            uint32_t descr = descrBase + descrInc;
            descrInc = (descrInc + 1) % ThreadCount;

            if (reverse(n, descr) > descr)
            {
                continue;
            }

            buildMat(n, mat, descr);
            float det = determinant(n, mat);
            if (det > maxDet)
            {
                maxDet = det;
                maxDescr = descr;
            }
        }

        MaxDetA[threadIdx] = maxDet;
        MaxDescrA[threadIdx] = maxDescr;

        threadBarrier();
        // Let main thread output results.
        threadBarrier();
    }

    delete[] mat;

    return 0;
}

static void printMat(int n, float mat[])
{
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < n; ++iRow)
    {
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < n; ++iCol)
        {
            std::cout << " " << mat[iRow * n + iCol];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        NMax = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (NMax > 16)
        {
            NMax = 16;
        }
    }

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        ThreadCount = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    MaxDetA = new float[ThreadCount];
    MaxDescrA = new uint32_t[ThreadCount];

    pthread_mutex_init(&ThreadMutex, 0);
    pthread_cond_init(&ThreadCond, 0);

    int* threadIdxA = new int[ThreadCount];
    pthread_t* threadA = new pthread_t[ThreadCount];

    for (int iThread = 0; iThread < ThreadCount; ++iThread)
    {
        threadIdxA[iThread] = iThread;
        pthread_create(threadA + iThread, 0, threadFunc, threadIdxA + iThread);
    }

    float* mat = new float[NMax * NMax];

    for (int n = 1; n <= NMax; ++n)
    {
        threadBarrier();

        float maxDet = 0.0f;
        uint32_t maxDescr = 0;

        for (int iThread = 0; iThread < ThreadCount; ++iThread)
        {
            if (MaxDetA[iThread] > maxDet)
            {
                maxDet = MaxDetA[iThread];
                maxDescr = MaxDescrA[iThread];
            }
        }

        std::cout << "n = " << n << " det = " << maxDet << std::endl;
        buildMat(n, mat, maxDescr);
        printMat(n, mat);

        threadBarrier();
    }

    delete[] mat;

    delete[] MaxDetA;
    delete[] MaxDescrA;

    delete[] threadIdxA;
    delete[] threadA;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's an interesting way of calculating the determinant of an integer matrix using only integer arithmetic: LU decomposition in some finite field (basically mod a large prime). I don't know if this would be faster.

Comment: @ThomasKwa That would probably still be O(n^3)? It might be helpful for larger matrices where floating point precision would otherwise become an issue. I didn't really look for literature. Well, I did a quick search, and found a paper about calculating determinants of Toeplitz matrices. But there were too many open questions for me to commit the time to try and implement it.

Comment: BTW, the killer here is really the exponential complexity for enumerating all matrices. But I don't even have the vaguest idea how to calculate the largest determinant without enumerating all of them. I thought about possibilities to at least cut out some unproductive values, but I got nothing on getting it down to polynomial complexity.

Comment: This is pretty amazing. Sadly it takes about 3 minutes for n = 15 however.  I was going to try it with n = 18, just for fun but I see you set a max of 16 in the code. Is there any reasons for that?

Comment: @Lembik This version of the code uses a 32-bit value for the bitmask, and it needs 2*n-1 bits for describing the matrix. I actually didn't compare if it's any slower with a 64-bit value. Probably wouldn't make much of a difference. However, at some point I think it will need `double` instead of `float` for the matrix to get the necessary precision. And I definitely expect that to slow it down. I initially started writing the code with generic types, but it looked kind of awkward. Since it was not going to go above 16 for this challenge, I hardwired the smaller types.

Comment: One cheap trick you can do is stop early if you get to the max for any 0,1 matrix from the OEIS.  Surprisingly this does happen sometimes.  In any case, if you can compute the values up to n=18 say it would be a great new OEIS entry in my view.

Comment: Just literally changing `float` to `double` didn't do it. Would you mind making a version that works for `n = 18` by any chance, please?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11909953/ is the modified version but it just gives 0 for n = 17.

Comment: @Lembik I'll try and take a look at it later today. I changed it to handle larger sizes for your other related challenge yesterday. Couldn't beat the highest scores for n=30 so far, my heuristics are stuck below 5*10^13.

Comment: @Lembik See http://paste.ubuntu.com/11915546 for code and http://paste.ubuntu.com/11915532 for results up to n=19.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thank you. So amazingly all the values found by the simple hill climbing are optimal up to n = 19 it seems!

Comment: @Lembik The results up to n=20 are at http://paste.ubuntu.com/11949738. They now list all the tied solutions, including attributes to quickly see the value of the diagonal and whether they are circulant. All of the maxima for m=18,19,20 are circulant matrices. Please double check the determinants before publishing them anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

## J

**Update: Improved code to search over half the values. Now calculates `n=12` comfortably within 120 seconds (down from 217s to 60s).**

You will need the latest version of [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/) installed.

```
#!/usr/bin/jconsole

dim =: -:@>:@#
take =: i.@dim
rotstack =: |."0 1~ take
toep =: (dim (|."1 @: {."1) rotstack)"1
det =: -/ . * @: toep
ps =: 3 : ',/(0 1 ,"0 1/ ,.y)'
canonical =: #. >: [: #. |. " 1

lss =: 3 : 0
  shape =. (2^y), y
  shape $ ,>{;/(y,2)$0 1
)

ls =: (canonical@:lss) # lss
ans =: >./ @: det @: ls @: <: @: +:

display =: 3 : 0
echo 'n = ';y;'the answer is';ans y
)
display"0 (1 + i.13)
exit''
```

---

Run this and kill when two minutes are up. My results (MBP 2014 - 16GB of RAM):

```
┌────┬─┬─────────────┬─┐
│n = │1│the answer is│1│
└────┴─┴─────────────┴─┘
┌────┬─┬─────────────┬─┐
│n = │2│the answer is│1│
└────┴─┴─────────────┴─┘
┌────┬─┬─────────────┬─┐
│n = │3│the answer is│2│
└────┴─┴─────────────┴─┘
┌────┬─┬─────────────┬─┐
│n = │4│the answer is│3│
└────┴─┴─────────────┴─┘
┌────┬─┬─────────────┬─┐
│n = │5│the answer is│5│
└────┴─┴─────────────┴─┘
┌────┬─┬─────────────┬─┐
│n = │6│the answer is│9│
└────┴─┴─────────────┴─┘
┌────┬─┬─────────────┬──┐
│n = │7│the answer is│32│
└────┴─┴─────────────┴──┘
┌────┬─┬─────────────┬──┐
│n = │8│the answer is│56│
└────┴─┴─────────────┴──┘
┌────┬─┬─────────────┬───┐
│n = │9│the answer is│125│
└────┴─┴─────────────┴───┘
┌────┬──┬─────────────┬───┐
│n = │10│the answer is│315│
└────┴──┴─────────────┴───┘
┌────┬──┬─────────────┬────┐
│n = │11│the answer is│1458│
└────┴──┴─────────────┴────┘
┌────┬──┬─────────────┬────┐
│n = │12│the answer is│2673│
└────┴──┴─────────────┴────┘
```

Total run time = 61.83s.

---

Just for fun

```
┌────┬──┬─────────────┬────┐
│n = │13│the answer is│8118│
└────┴──┴─────────────┴────┘
```

This took approximately 210 seconds on its own.

Comment: Note to testers: `n = 12` requires roughly 18 GiB of memory.

Comment: This is a very nice improvement. The output is slightly buggy however. For me using  j64-804 it outputs n =1 twice so it is out by one for ever more.

Comment: @Lembik Ah that's right. I just updated the code; could you try running again? Thanks! (I have set it to calculate up to `n=13`. You can change the `13` in the second-to-last line to have it calculate up whatever you wish.)

Comment: I ran it again and it still gets to 12.

Comment: @Lembik Hmm .. are you saying it gets to 12 within the time limit and gets to 13 some time after that (which is what I expect), or that it never gets to 13 (i.e. program halts after 12)?

Comment: @Legendre The former.

Comment: @Lembik Ah yes, that is to be expected. Calculating up to `n=13` takes about 7 minutes on my Macbook Pro. (The `n=13` itself is like ~4 minutes). Until I think of a better algorithm, `n=12` is the best I can manage in the time allotted :)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2

This is a very straightforward solution, and probably won't win the contest. But hey, it works!

I'll give a quick overview of what exactly is happening.

1. I first generate every possible starting row for `n`. For example, when `n=2`, this will generate an array length 2<sup>n+1</sup>, where each row is length 2n-1. It would look like this: `[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]`.
2. Then, for each of those possible starting rows, I rotate it `n` times and slice off the first `n` items to generate the appropriate matrix, and use `scipy` to calculate the determinant, all while keeping track of the maximum value. At the end of this, I simply print out the maximum, increment `n` by 1, and keep going until 10 minutes has passed.

To run this, you will need [scipy](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html) installed.

*Edit 1: Changed how initial rows were built by using itertools.product instead, thanks Sp3000!*

*Edit 2: Removed storage of possible starting rows for a minimal improvement in speed.*

*Edit 3: Changed to `scipy` to have more control over how `det` worked.*

```py
from scipy import linalg
from collections import deque
from time import time
from itertools import product

c=1
t=time()
while 1:
    m=0
    for d in product(range(2),repeat=2*c-1):
        a=deque(d)
        l=[d[0:c]]
        for x in xrange(c-1):
            a.rotate(1)
            l+=[list(a)[0:c]]
        m=max(m,linalg.det(l,overwrite_a=True,check_finite=False))
    print m,'in',time()-t,'s'
    c+=1
```

Here's some sample output on my home machine (i7-4510U, 8GB RAM):

```py
1.0 in 0.0460000038147 s
1.0 in 0.0520000457764 s
2.0 in 0.0579998493195 s
3.0 in 0.0659999847412 s
5.0 in 0.0829999446869 s
9.0 in 0.134999990463 s
32.0 in 0.362999916077 s
56.0 in 1.28399991989 s
125.0 in 5.34999990463 s
315.0 in 27.6089999676 s
1458.0 in 117.513000011 s
```

Comment: Thank you but I think you have answered an old version of the question I am afraid. It is now about Toeplitz matrices and the time limit is 2 minutes.

Comment: I see so much golfed Python on this site that I often forget that for general purposes it's actually a readable language.

Comment: This could probably be sped up significantly, because it doesn't take advantage of the fact that it's a binary matrix.

Comment: @ThomasKwa If I'm honest, I have no idea how to take advantage of that :P

Comment: Quote from numpy documentation: "The determinant is computed via LU factorization using the LAPACK routine z/dgetrf." I looked at dgetrf, and it says it uses double precision; depending on OP's GPU single precision could be faster.

Comment: Makes it to 11 now on my machine!

Answer (score 4):

## C++

Bruteforce with use of OpenMP for parallelization and simple optimization to avoid evaluation of determinant for transposed matrices.

```
$ lscpu
...
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
...
$ g++ -O2 toepl.cpp -fopenmp
$ timeout 2m ./a.out 
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 5
6 9
7 32
8 56
9 125
10 315
11 1458
12 2673
13 8118
14 22386
```

```cpp
#include <cmath>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void updateReverses(vector < int > & reverses) {
  int reversesCnt = reverses.size();
  for(int i = 0; i < reversesCnt; ++i){
    reverses[i] <<= 1;
    reverses.push_back(reverses[i] | 1);
  }
}

const double eps = 1e-9;

double determinant(vector < vector < double > > & matrix) {
  int n = matrix.size();
  double det = 1;
  if(n == 1) return matrix[0][0];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    int p = i;
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
      if(fabs(matrix[j][i]) > fabs(matrix[p][i]))
        p = j;
    if(fabs(matrix[p][i]) < eps)
      return 0;
    matrix[i].swap(matrix[p]);
    if(i != p) det *= -1;
    det *= matrix[i][i];
    matrix[i][i] = 1. / matrix[i][i];
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
      matrix[i][j] *= matrix[i][i];
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j){
      if(fabs(matrix[j][i]) < eps) continue;
      for(int k = i + 1; k < n; ++k)
        matrix[j][k] -= matrix[i][k] * matrix[j][i];
    }
  }
  return det;
}

int main() {
  vector < int > reverses(1, 0);
  reverses.reserve(1 << 30);
  updateReverses(reverses);
  for(int n = 1;; ++n){
    double res = 0;
    int topMask = 1 << (2 * n - 1);
    vector < vector < double > > matrix(n, vector < double > (n));
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:res) firstprivate(matrix) schedule(dynamic,1<<10)
    for(int mask = 0; mask < topMask; ++mask){
      if(mask < reverses[mask]) continue;
      for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
          matrix[i][j] = (mask >> (i - j + n - 1)) & 1;
      res = max(res, determinant(matrix));
    }
    cout << n << ' ' << res << endl;
    updateReverses(reverses);
    updateReverses(reverses);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you may soon be making your first OEIS entry unless someone comes up with a clever idea :)

Answer (score 2):

## R

You'll have to install R and the packages listed with `install.packages("package_name")`

Didn't get under 2 mins on my machine with this version (I've to try with a parallel modification)

```r
library(pracma)
library(stringr)
library(R.utils)
library(microbenchmark)

f <- function(n) {
  #If n is 1, return 1 to avoid code complexity on this special case
  if(n==1) { return(1) }
  # Generate matrices and get their determinants
  dets <- sapply(strsplit(intToBin( 0:(2^n - 1)), ""), function(x) {
              sapply( strsplit( intToBin( 0:(2^(n-1) - 1) ), ""), 
                    function(y) { 
                      det(Toeplitz(x,c(x[1],y))) 
                    })

              })
  #Get the maximum determinant and return it
  res <- max(abs(dets))
  return(res)
}
```

Call and output:

```
> sapply(1:10,f)
 [1]   1   1   2   3   5   9  32  56 125 315
```

Benchmark on my machine:

```
> microbenchmark(sapply(1:10,f),times=1L)
Unit: seconds
            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 sapply(1:10, f) 66.35315 66.35315 66.35315 66.35315 66.35315 66.35315     1
```

For information, for a 1:11 range, it takes 285 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## C

Compile with:

```
$ clang -Ofast 52851.c -o 52851
```

Run with:

```
$ ./52851
```

Can output the maximum determinant for `n = 1..10` in ~115 seconds on my computer.

The program is just getting the determinant every possible binary Toeplitz matrix of size `n`, however every determinant of matrices of size `5x5` or smaller will be cached using memoization.

At first I wrongly assumed that every submatrix of a Toeplitz matrix will also be a Toeplitz matrix, so I only needed to memoize `2^(2n-1)` values instead of `2^(n^2)` for each `n`. I made the program before realizing my mistake, so this submission is just a fix of that program.

---

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ELEMENTS(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x))

int *dets[6];

void print_matrix(int n, int c) {
    for(int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
            int j = n - 1 - row + col;
            int val = !!(c & (1 << j));
            printf("%d ", val);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

int det(int n, uint8_t *m) {
    if(n == 1) {
        return m[0];
    }

    int i = 0;

    if(n < ELEMENTS(dets)) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n * n; j++) {
            i *= 2;
            i += m[j];
        }

        int v = dets[n][i];
        if(v != INT_MIN) {
            return v;
        }
    }

    int v = 0;

    uint8_t *sub = malloc((n - 1) * (n - 1));

    for(int removed = 0; removed < n; removed++) {
        if(m[removed]) {
            uint8_t *p = sub;
            for(int row = 1; row < n; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
                    if(col == removed) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    *p = m[col + row * n];

                    p++;
                }
            }

            v += (removed % 2 == 0? 1: -1) * det(n - 1, sub);
        }
    }

    free(sub);

    if(n < ELEMENTS(dets)) {
        dets[n][i] = v;
    }
    return v;
}

int main(void) {
    for(int i = 2; i < ELEMENTS(dets); i++) {
        int combinations = 1 << (i * i);
        dets[i] = malloc(combinations * sizeof(**dets));
        for(int j = 0; j < combinations; j++) {
            dets[i][j] = INT_MIN;
        }
    }

    puts("1: 1");

    for(int n = 2; n < 65; n++) {
        int vars = 2 * n - 1;
        size_t combinations = 1 << vars;

        int best = -1;
        int max = -1;

        uint8_t *sub = malloc((n - 1) * (n - 1));

        for(int c = 0; c < combinations; c++) {
            int d = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if(c & (1 << (n - 1 + i))) {
                    uint8_t *p = sub;
                    for(int row = 1; row < n; row++) {
                        for(int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
                            if(col == i) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            int j = n - 1 - row + col;
                            *p = !!(c & (1 << j));

                            p++;
                        }
                    }
                    d += (i % 2 == 0? 1: -1) * det(n - 1, sub);
                }
            }

            if(d > max) {
                max = d;
                best = c;
            }
        }

        free(sub);

        printf("%d: %d\n", n, max);
        //print_matrix(n, best);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're calculating the determinant using expansion by minors; this has `O(n!)` complexity, so you may be better off using a different algorithm.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I didn't know that there were faster algorithms, so yeah this solution is pretty bad.

Comment: You may want to look into using [LU Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Decomposition_methods) to find the determinant of a matrix.  It's `O(n^3)`, I believe, though can be made faster with some interesting algorithms. I believe most of the builtins used here generally use a variant of decomposition to perform determinants.

Comment: @BrainSteel, yeah I looked at it, but I might as well go for a `O(n^2)` algorithm if I'm updating my answer.

Comment: According to a casual Wikipedia search, the determinant of a Toeplitz matrix can be determined in `O(n^2)`. But I think the bottleneck of the problem is searching among the `O(4^n)` many 0-1 `n` by `n` matrices.

Comment: @Legendre Maybe writing O(n^2) code to compute the determinant of a Toeplitz matrix could be a PPCG challenge on its own?

Comment: @Lembik I digged around the literature some more. It seems that even the `O(n^2)` algorithm (there are better ones) is a serious algorithm --- not hard to code up _per se_, but not something that is easily "golfable".

Comment: @Legendre Right. There should be a way to pose serious coding challenges which aren't related to golf on PPCG though.

Answer (score 1):

## PARI/GP, n=11

This is brute force but taking advantage of `det(A^T) = det(A)`. I'm only posting it to demonstrate how easy it is to skip transposes. The lowest bit of `b1` holds the top left cell, and the other bits hold the rest of the top row. `b2` holds the rest of the left column. We simply enforce `b2 <= (b1>>1)`.

```
{ for(n=1,11,
    res=0;
    for(b1=0,2^n-1,
      for(b2=0,b1>>1,
        res=max(res,matdet(matrix(n,n,i,j,bittest(if(i>j,b2>>(i-j-1),b1>>(j-i)),0))));
      )
    );
    print(n" "res);
  )
}
```

Regarding computing Toeplitz determinants in `O(n^2)` time: In my limited research, I've kept running into a requirement that all leading principal minors must be nonzero in order for the algorithms to work, which is a major obstacle for this task. Feel free to give me pointers if you know more about this than I do.

Comment: Did you see this paper? http://www.scienpress.com/upload/JAMB/Vol%201_1_4.pdf . It wasn't clear to me what the complexity is. There seemed to be quite a lot of terms for the n=5 example.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes I saw that. It seems the complexity is not polynomial, considering that e.g. `e_{k+1}` has 4 times the number of components as `e_k`. There are many omissions in the paper. An invertible matrix has an LU decomposition iff all leading principal minors are nonzero. (Notice the denominators, e.g. `a_0` -- implicitly they are guaranteed to be nonzero.) Uniqueness comes from L being unit triangular. The author also didn't mention numerical stability. In case the link becomes unavailable, the paper is "On Calculating the Determinants of Toeplitz Matrices" by Hsuan-Chu Li (2011).

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, \$n \leq 14 \$ in 2 min on my laptop

#### `src/main.rs`

```rust
use std::time::{Instant, Duration};
use rulinalg::matrix::Matrix;

fn bit_get(n: u32, i: u32) -> f64 {
    ((n >> i) & 1) as f64
}

fn main() {
    let start = Instant::now();
    let max_duration = Duration::from_secs(120); // 2 minutes

    let mut n = 1;

    while start.elapsed() < max_duration {
        let mut res = 0f64;
        for b1 in 0..(1 << n) {
            for b2 in 0..=(b1 / 2) {
                let values: Vec<f64> = (0..n)
                    .flat_map(|r| (0..n)
                        .map(move |c| if r > c {
                            bit_get(b2, r as u32 - c as u32 - 1)
                        } else {
                            bit_get(b1 as u32, c as u32 - r as u32)
                        }))
                    .collect();
                let matrix = Matrix::new(n as usize, n as usize, values);
                let det = matrix.det();
                res = res.max(det);
            }
        }
        println!("{} {}", n, res);
        n += 1;
    }
}
```

#### `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "rust_hello"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
ndarray = "0.15"
ndarray-linalg = "0.13"
rulinalg = "0.4"
```

#### Build and running

```
# win10 environment

$ set Copt-level=3
$ set Clto=fat
$ set Ctarget-cpu=native
$ cargo build --release
$ target\release\rust_hello.exe
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 5
6 9
7 32
8 56
9 125
10 315
11 1458
12 2673
13 8117.999999999997  # roughly 8118
14 22386.000000000007 # roughly 22386
```

Comment: Any chance for 13?

Comment: @Simd I have updated the Rust code, now \$n \leq 14 \$ in 2 min on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica

So slow. It can be optimized more.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY9BawIxEIXv@yseu@ChjtTkulWwLUoPhR56C1OalYgLcRfSHCzib9/OGJtLmJfvvZc5@XwMJ5/7vZ@mlxh8cvUujp2P3w81t9Wn72JwKfxghWVbYTsm1xkdCHI/rWC/BixgdJzPCRUKY@@MVWYbx5vv0bJKdw7Sm/qzgDpgk5L/dW8H1xis0VjCc593IUsWQbSFaNrExaznH5D221tjmDEjXAbCcCUsZQPByvff/VkXIbyKpVQzt6zIR@qH7MRUoybFuWRIrjFXnqY/)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Table[res = 0;
 For[b1 = 0, b1 <= 2^n - 1, b1++, 
  For[b2 = 0, b2 <= Floor[b1/2], b2++, 
   matrix = 
    Array[If[#1 > #2, BitGet[b2, #1 - #2 - 1], 
       BitGet[b1, #2 - #1]] &, {n, n}, 0];
   res = Max[res, Det[matrix]];]];
 Print[n, " ", res], {n, 1, 11}]
```

```
1,1,2,3,5,9,32,56,125,315,1458
```